# Google Cloud APIs & Services

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, url, service, credentials

ON console.cloud.google.com -> APIs & Services -> Credentials -> OAuth 2.0 Client IDs.

We are adding our client dealers URLs in both(Authorized JavaScript origins and Authorized redirect URIs). Currently the count of dealers has been reached 58 in Authorized JavaScript origin and 58 Authorized redirect URIs.

Could you please help us to confirm is google has set any limit count on URLs or we can add any many as we want.

If there is any limitation what is the way forward of this how we can increase this limit?

Thanks

If there is any limitation what is the way forward of this how we can increase this limit?